# facebook app access token mismatch error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token

I am trying to send notifications to users via facebook canvas app(SDK 5). My notification code

```
$response = $fb->post('/userID/notifications?access_token='."$appAccessToken".'&template="test template"&href="test htrf"');
```

But I am getting an error "Uncaught exception 'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException' with message 'Access token mismatch. The access token provided in the FacebookRequest and the one provided in the URL or POST params do not match"

I have checked the app access token in graph api explorer and its working fine! I tried to reset the app secret but same error

graph api explorer have no problem with the app access token but when i try to paste the app access token  it in my code it shows the error.

I have tried to make app access token by combining app_id|app_secret but no luck.

am i doing it wrong? 
Thanks

Comment: Pass parameters to the `post` method as described in the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/Facebook/5.0.0#post